# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "(double _a, double _b, double _c)" в "ConsoleApp3.MoveList"

Tags: c#

У меня возникла ошибка о том что: Ошибка    CS0029  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "(double _a, double _b, double _c)" в "ConsoleApp3.MoveList". Когда пытаюсь вернуть через return наши переменные. Ошибка находится в этом статическом методе: public static new MoveList Vvod()

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Equaltion
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;

        public Equaltion(double _a, double _b, double _c)
        {
            this.a = _a;
            this.b = _b;
            this.c = _c;
        }

        public double A
        {
            get { return a; }
            set { a = value; }
        }
        public double B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = value; }
        }
        public double C
        {
            get { return c; }
            set { c = value; }
        }

        public void Reshenie()
        {
            try
            {
                double D = Math.Pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
                if (D > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Уравнение имеет два корня");
                    double x1 = (1 * b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                    double x2 = (1 * b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                    Console.WriteLine("x1 = {0}; x2 = {1}", x1, x2);
                }
                else if (D == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Уравнение имеет один корень");
                    double x = (-1 * b) / (2 * a);
                    Console.WriteLine("x = {0}", x);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Возникло исключение: уравнение не имеет вещественных корней. {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Исключение обработано");
            }
        }
        public virtual void Vvod()
        {
        }
        public virtual void Info()
        {
        }
    }
    public class MoveList : Equaltion
    {
        private double ma { get; set; }
        public MoveList() : base(0, 0, 0)
        {
            Ma = ma;
        }
        public double Ma
        {
            get { return ma; }
            set
            {
                if (value == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Коллич опер");
                ma = value;
            }
        }
        public static new MoveList Vvod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите переменую а:");
            double _a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите переменую b:");
            double _b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите переменую c:");
            double _c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            return (_a,_b,_c);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
       
            Console.WriteLine("Сколько создать листов:");
            int lis = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List<Equaltion> spisoks = new List<Equaltion>();
            for (int i = 0; i < lis; i++)
            {
                MoveList m = MoveList.Vvod();
                spisoks.Add(m);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `return new MoveList(_a,_b,_c);`

Comment: да работает спасибо! @aepot. Только у меня конструктор без параметров, спасибо return new MoveList(); . Спасибо